# Spinner funciones que puede hacer

Tags: android, spinner

Quiero usar un *Spinner* pero necesito que la opción de la lista del *Spinner* que toque me cargue otra lista de opciones en la misma *Activity*.

Ejemplo de lo que busco hacer:

```
Spinner 1______
               opción 1_____
                            Lista 1
               opción 2_____
                            Lsita 2
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Cristian!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]** en base a este documento modifica tu pregunta, es recomendable agregar lo que has intentado, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitas es colocarle un escuchador como por ejemplo asi

```
Spinner aux = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.IDSPINNER);
final ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter7 = new ArrayAdapter<>(TuClase.this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, Datos);
        dataAdapter7.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        txtFechaMesExpedicion.setAdapter(dataAdapter7);
 aux.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                Object tipo = dataAdapter7.getItem(position);
                if(tipo.toString.compareTo("Opcion1")==0){
                --Aca llamas al metodo que necesites
              }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter) {
                // no se necesita
            }
        });
```

avisa como te fue

Comment: gracias lo voy a implementar y te comento como me fue

Comment: donde me indica (acá llamas al método ) como lo coloco ?

Comment: Ya cargue el código como indicas y me da un error en:

Comment: tipo.toString.compareTo